# Assign an ID to a DIV using javascript

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to assign an ID to a DIV that already has a Class attached to it. Here's my code:
(The class is "myclass" and the id is "myid")

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".myclass").id("myid");
 });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is jQuery, not pure JavaScript please tag properly in the future.

Comment: Is there more than one element with that class?

Comment: Thanks @ShadowWizard, will do in the future.

Comment: @RightSaidFred Nope, just the one class that I'm trying to add an ID to.

Answer (score 4):

Try with [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) if you use jQuery 1.6+ or [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) otherwise:

```
$(".myclass").prop("id", "myid");
```

If you have more than one element with that class, it will assign same ID to multiple elements which is very bad practice.. in this case append the index:

```
$(".myclass").each(function(index) {
    $(this).prop("id", "myid" + index);
});
```

**Edit**:

Most elegant and efficient way is using `.prop()` or `.attr()` (in pre 1.6) directly without `.each()` then assigning the `id` of the direct DOM element:

```
$(".myclass").prop("id", function(index) {
    return "myid" + index;
});
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/MkgTG/2/).

Comment: @Tom true, but what if he got more than one?

Comment: +1 for `.prop()`, but in the `.each()`, I'd suggest skipping the method and using the property directly.

Comment: The point was the clarification of (don't mess with same ID for bunch of elements). You've correctly edited your comment hehehe. @RightSaidFred you can't use it directly, because you'll have more than 1 .myclass in some time.

Comment: `.attr` and `.prop` can take functions as arguments to automatically loop `.each` for you, so you don't need the separate `.each`.

Comment: @TomRoggero: Why would that make a difference in the `.each` loop? You'd just change the code to `this.id = "myid" + index`.

Comment: @RightSaidFred also correct, no need to wrap the element.. see my edit. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's not quite what I meant. It should be `$(".myclass").prop('id', function(i) { return "myid" + i; })` OR `$(".myclass").each(function(i) { this.id = "myid" + i; });`. Combining both defeats the purpose of using 'prop' at all.

Comment: @Logan you're totally right, I had a blonde moment! Edited now, thanks. :)

Comment: @RightSaidFred yep, I agree. But someone could do $(".myclass).prop('id', 'something'); which would be wrong. It's worth  the edit of using 2nd param as function for iteration.

Comment: @TomRoggero: Yes, I'm with you on that.

Answer (score 2):

It's

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".myclass").eq(0).attr("id", "myid");
});
```

I wrote *eq(0)* because there cannot be two DOM elements with same ID, but there could be more than one *.myclass*

Comment: Why not: `$(".myclass")[0].id = "myid";`?  Several less function calls and one less jQuery object.

Comment: @jfriend00 it will crash with error when there's no element with that class.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.attr()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".myclass").attr("id","myid");
 });
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/LFQeR/

Comment: This could set multiple selements all to the same id.

Comment: In the question its not made clear if there are one or multiple div with same class and he wants to set the id just to one div or all divs

Comment: "Is there more than one element with that class? Nope,just the one class that I'm trying to add an ID to" - this is the comment posted by the question raiser